# Find all classes involved in a method call

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2013

- I have a .NET 4.0 C# Solution with a single **`.csproj`** (Library) having several thousand files.
- I want to extract out a small subset of the functionality from the thousands of files.

e.g. I want to extract the functionality of the `MyLibrary.RelevantMethod()` method into another library.

The aim is to create a new `.csproj` with the bare minimum class files needed to achieve this functionality.

- i have a **`Program.cs`** which invokes the functionality and i can navigate through the flow to find all classes involved. Just that there are too many. (still a small subset of all classes)

**Solutions tried:**

- the usual brute force of going through the flow from the method (F12) and copying over every class file and associated files needed for it to compile. this is taking a lot of time, but i know that if i keep at it, it'll be done. so that is **what i am doing right now.**
- other option was to copy over the whole project and eliminate folders of classes based on instinct/name space references, build to verify and keep at it. this got nasty because a subset of classes in a folder were needed.
- the vs 2013 code-map graphs became unmanageable in 3 drill downs. sequence diagrams became too complex as well.
- Call hierarchy seemed to be the most promising showing all the classes involved visually but there is still the manual task of drilling through and copying the classes.

while i manually continue extracting the class one-by-one using the call hierarchy, is there a **faster way** or a more **automated** way (semi works as well) to determine all the classes involved in a method call in C#?

if i can get the list, i can do a search on the physical folders nesting the .cs. files (every class has an equivalent .cs file) and just copy them over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all classes involved in a method call with the [Runtime Flow](http://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) tool (developed by me). From the Runtime Summary window you can also copy these classes to the Clipboard for the selected module or a namespace.